# Sending mail without authentication using nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, sendmail

I'm able to send email with any email address without password in a Linux machine using sendmail. Is there any option like this to do it programmatically using node.js in windows?

Comment: You might want to take a look at nodemailer module https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer

Comment: @Ben nodemailer asks for authentication

Comment: @NagaLakshmi then you're probably not using it correctly. Take a look at the [`nodemailer-sendmail-transport`](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-sendmail-transport) module.

Answer (score 4):

Use [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/).  This will give you two options:

1. You can [remove `auth`](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/lib/smtp-transport/index.js#L56) from the example code when creating a [SMTP Transport](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#examples) message if you have [local IIS SMTP turned on](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058(v=ws.10).aspx).  Obviously, set `host: 'localhost'` and the other settings to match your SMTP.
2. Alternatively, you *might* be able to make use of [sendmail-transport](https://nodemailer.com/transports/sendmail/) with some third party software such as [Sendmail for Windows](https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/) . SMW emulates the unix method.  Unfortunately, SMW is no longer maintained.

Comment: this answer seems to be making some assumptions that Window is involved in some way (IIS, Sendmail for Windows).  Can you address how to proceed if this is not the case?

Comment: @Michael you clearly failed to read the question in which a windows solution is specifically asked for.

Comment: @tremor Ah, so I did... oops

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend take a look at the [sendmail](https://github.com/guileen/node-sendmail) library which does not need any smtp/auth to send email. It gives you similar experience to using `sendmail` in linux server.

```
const sendmail = require('sendmail')();

sendmail({
  from: 'test@finra.org',
  to: 'YOUR@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Hello World',
  html: 'Mail of test sendmail '
}, function (err, reply) {
  console.log(err && err.stack)
  console.dir(reply)
})
```